# (Excel) Calculate equation with different values of (x)

Tags: excel, function, variables, formula

I want to calculate an equation with a variable in it. I want to list variable values in a row, then excel should list all results according to this values;

```
y(x) = 5x + 4
```

I need y(1), y(2), y(3) which results 9, 14, 19 etc.

Is there a way to do that in excel?

Comment: Put `=5*a1+4` in B1 then your values in column A and drag down?

Comment: An alternative to @findwindow's suggestion is to highlight a range (say A1:A3), and type `=5*{1;2;3}+4` and enter with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.  This will populate A1:A3 with the respective answers, 9, 14, and 19.

Comment: @brucewayne is there any way to make  this datas get from rows. Because the values could be changed according to further calculations of other parts.

Comment: Did @findwindow's method not work? That's probably your best bet. My suggestion was just another way to do it, and also I'm learning how to use arrays in formulas, which that has, so I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you for your answers. Below solution suits my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one variable data table would give you what your looking for. See [Excel data table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-b7dd17be-e12d-4e72-8ad8-f8148aa45635)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I look for. I wonder another thing: Can I populate this data table with a logic like; x= 0.4, 0.8, 1.2,....n